# How to create a fcgi script with Mojo::Server::FastCGI

Tags: perl, fastcgi, mojolicious, mojo

How can I create a fast cgi script that uses Mojo::Server::FastCGI and runs my application?
My application currently uses "plack" and "app->run" function from Mojolicious::Lite. What should I change?